# python :i need to group similar items of a dictionary into a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, group-by, split

I have the following dictionary in python.

```
{731819:
[
{'lprods': ['5261', '5247', '5246'],'rprods':['123','456'],'cond':'a1'},
{'lprods': ['5261', '5547', '5246'],'rprods':['1223','496'],'cond':'a1'},
{'lprods': ['526', '557', '5246'],'rprods':['223','496'],'cond':'f1'},
{'lprods': ['61', '47', '246'],'rprods':['23','96'],'cond':'a0'}
]
}
```

I need to get the output based on 'cond'.
the items with same 'cond' should be grouped together in a list.
The output should be:

```
a1=[
[['5261', '5247', '5246'],['123','456']],
[['5261', '5547', '5246'],['1223','496']]
]
f1=[['526', '557', '5246'],['223','496']]
a0=[['61', '47', '246'],['23','96']]
```

the contents of the array are lprods and rprods.

In fact the items with same cond should be in a single list.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a dict as a result:

```
result = {}
for e in d[731819]:
    result.setdefault(e['cond'], []).extend([e['lprods'],e['rprods'] ])
```

result

```
result
```

output:

```
{'a1': [['5261', '5247', '5246'],
  ['123', '456'],
  ['5261', '5547', '5246'],
  ['1223', '496']],
 'f1': [['526', '557', '5246'], ['223', '496']],
 'a0': [['61', '47', '246'], ['23', '96']]}
```

Comment: Your answer is now better than my old one :-) +1

Comment: @SoniaThomas if this solves your issue you can accept the answer, thx